# How do I refactor findViewById without class cast exception?

Tags: android, classcastexception, findviewbyid

Usually when I have many elements in my android app, onCreate looks like this:

```
  onCreate(){

   ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b1) ;
   ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b2) ;
   ImageVuew v3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.v3) ;
   ViewSwitcher v4 = (ViewSwitcher)findViewbyId(R.id.v4) ;
   TextView v5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.v5) ;

   //and so on
  }
```

Android requires to do this class cast for every text,image,button etc in the app. But text,image,button,switcher **are all subclasses of View class!**

I try to add all views into one array of Views and loop through like this:

```
  View[]clickableViews = {forkImageView, patronImageView,cabelImageView1,cabelImageView2, bulb_switcher,doublePlugImageView,kettleBaseImageView,kettleSwitcher} ;

    int []image_views_ids = {R.id.forkImage, R.id.patronImage, R.id.bulb_switcher, R.id.cabel1, R.id.cabel2, R.id.longcabel, R.id.kettle_base, R.id.kettleSwitcher};

    for( int i = 0 ; i < clickableViews.length;i++){
            clickableViews[i] = findViewById(image_views_ids[i]);
    }
```

It may throw class cast exception

Is there a way to still do it smart way?

Comment: But then forkImageView (for example) isn't set by this loop, is it? You have an array of Views, but you can only get them by dereferencing the array... right?

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to cast.  If you're only doing something that's defined by View, for example adding an on click listener, just declare it as a View and don't cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [library Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), I think its what you are looking for. It will make your code cleaner :)

The example from the website is:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @InjectView(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @InjectView(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
  @InjectView(R.id.footer) TextView footer;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    // TODO Use "injected" views...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast into View class,too.

Your code will be like:

```
View[]clickableViews = {forkImageView, patronImageView,cabelImageView1,cabelImageView2, bulb_switcher,doublePlugImageView,kettleBaseImageView,kettleSwitcher} ;

        int []image_views_ids = {R.id.forkImage, R.id.patronImage, R.id.bulb_switcher, R.id.cabel1, R.id.cabel2, R.id.longcabel, R.id.kettle_base, R.id.kettleSwitcher};

        for( int i = 0 ; i < clickableViews.length;i++){
                clickableViews[i] =(View)findViewById(image_views_ids[i]);
        }
```